# Padded data in a HTML Table does not line up

Tags: html, perl

I am using Perl to read data from a file into an array then using HTML::Template to display the data in a HTML page. All I am doing is reading the data into the array line by line and outputting it.

Or I was until I noticed that the data in the middle section of the file was misaligned on the web page. I then wrote some Perl code to pad the first part of the line and then add the second column back in. Example on the web page:

```
T - Online Transmit Done                                    R - Online Request Allowed 
E - Extracted batch                                      M - Multiple transmission 
P - Transmission in Progress                                  U - Batch Unextractable 
N - Batch Nontransmittable                                  B - BSC
```

If I copy and paste the data from the web page I get this perfectly aligned:

```
T - Online Transmit Done                                    R - Online Request Allowed 
E - Extracted batch                                         M - Multiple transmission 
P - Transmission in Progress                                U - Batch Unextractable 
N - Batch Nontransmittable                                  B - BSC
```

Where am I going wrong? The data is showing as correctly padded but not inside a table on an HTML page. Here is the HTML I am using, nothing fancy:

```
<TABLE BORDER=1 ALIGN="center">
    <TR>
        <TD ALIGN="center"><B>DATA</B></TD>
    </TR>

    <TMPL_LOOP NAME="THIS_LOOP">
    <TR>
         <TD ALIGN="left"><TMPL_VAR NAME="DATA"></TD>
    </TR>
    </TMPL_LOOP>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Although when I submitted this it lost the formatting. Each line starts with data data padded to 50 characters and then the second set of data is added to the end of each line.

Comment: What do you mean "added 2nd column back in"? Your table only has one column. You can't really (and don't want to) align with spaces.

Comment: OK then how to split the data in the middle of the loop using HTML::Template to put it into two columns then switch back to a single column?  I split the line in the Perl code, pad the left side to 50 characters and then JOIN the right side of the data back on. It then displays on the web page missaglined but if I cut and paste what is on the HTML page to say notepad++ the padding has worked and the JOIN on every line starts at 51 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces), like Courier, for your table data. Your columns aren't lining up because the font you are using has different widths for different letters.

But positioning elements with spaces is not a good idea. It'd be worthwhile to rethink your layout / logic and use tables as they were intended to be used.

Comment: Thanks, I think you have a very valid point - use Tables as they should be used! HTML is not my background so I had hoped on Friday night just to dump all the data into a single column table. I have reworked the Perl code and now I just need to remember how HTML tables work.